# Why can't I scroll down the right-click menu on my 2nd monitor?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Please see the screenshot beneath. As I can't scroll down the right-click menu on my 2nd monitor, I must unproductively move the window on my 2nd monitor to my 1st every time I need one of the options in the red box.

I'm using Windows 10, [Dell M-UVDEL1 mouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000VBZWZ6), but no mouse self-helper software.

[image]

Comment: Questions: Which Windows version? Which mouse? And have you installed any mouse helper product? Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc I edited my post to answer the first three questions there. I'll get back to you on Safe mode.

Comment: Your screen resolution must be pretty low if the context menu does not fit.

Comment: Maybe consider removing software you don’t need? IIRC there was also software that allowed reorganizing the context menu, that could also help if you truly need all this stuff.

Comment: The secondary screen is 1024x768. The visible part of the context menu has *at least* 17 entries from third-party software, which is *a lot*. // That being said, the source of the problem is probably the mixed-DPI setup.

Comment: @DanielB: I count 38 entries in the menu, which IS enormous. Where do you see 1024x768?

Comment: @harrymc By measuring the screen size in the screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried setting the highest resolution on the second monitor? are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: @DanielB What software?  I edited my picture to exhibit the screen resolutions. In future, feel free to ask me!

Comment: @harrymc I edited my picture to exhibit the screen resolutions. In future, feel free to ask me!

Comment: It's almost like your monitor #2 has ctrl depressed automagically when you right click. Try shift + Right click on monitor 2.

Comment: @BenPlont `Shift` + Right click on monitor 2 didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your context menu is the largest I have ever seen, with 38 items out of which 17
are added by various installed applications.
On the other hand, while your primary monitor is large, your secondary monitor
is extremely small.
For these reasons the context menu does not fit on the secondary monitor.

The problem of scrolling can be a new Windows bug, but can also be created by
some installed application.

This can be verified by booting in Safe mode. If the problem disappears,
then this is caused by an application, and you may use
the free
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to disable/re-enable startup items until you locate the problem.

If Safe mode disables the display driver, when it is also third-party,
you could instead try a selective
[clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows),
disabling only system services that have no connection to display.

If the problem continues in Safe mode, this is a Windows bug.
You may report it to Microsoft using the Feedback Hub, but the only real solution
will be to reduce the size of the context menu by disabling rarely needed
entries.

The best way, if the product supports it, is to go into a product's
Settings/Preferences and disable that option for the context menu.

If the product does not support such an option, you may still force the issue.
You may use here again Autoruns to disable entries from the "Explorer" tab.
You may also find many other such free context-menu editors in the article
[Best Free Context Menu Extensions list](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-right-click-context-menu-add-ons.htm).

Comment: Hi! I just entered Safe Mode, but there the computer doesn't acknowledge or exhibit monitor #2? But there's nothing with it, because right after I left Safe Mode and booted, Monitor #2 reappeared.

Comment: Hi again. Have you had the possibility to see my comment above? If so, can you please edit your post to remove the para. on "This can be verified by booting in Safe mode" as it's outdated?

Comment: I have added another option that may work better than Safe boot when the display driver is third-party and is also disabled.