# How does 'Cut' differ from 'Delete' in the context menu?

Tags: context-menu

User harrymc recommended me to [remove items in the context menu](https://superuser.com/a/1433478/269574).

1. So please distinguish 'Cut'  from 'Delete'?
2. If I must remove, which ought I remove?

Comment: You won't be able to "remove" `delete` and `cut` from the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut - Copies the item to the clipboard and then deletes from the current location. If you want to move something, you generally cut and then paste the item elsewhere.

Delete - Deletes the item from the current location without copying it to the clipboard. In windows this will move the item to the recycle bin, unless you press the shift key while clicking delete, which permanently deletes the item.

I would remove most of the 3rd party items listed in your context menu, the "convert to PDF" and so on (unless you use them often, of course). If some of those are things you don't use, or didn't even know you had, I would remove the associated program entirely in the Add/Removes Programs part of the Windows.